# Do you have any good ideas (settings) for displaying titles with a lot of characters in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

When there are too many characters in the title of this section, it is very difficult to see. Therefore, I would like to limit the number of characters in the part that is always visible. Also, I would like to be able to see all the letters of the title in the popup when the mouse is hovered.

[This is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykhi/gwnp3fcm/28/)

```js
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/7.1.1/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/7.1.1/modules/venn.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/7.1.1/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/7.1.1/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  accessibility: {
    point: {
      descriptionFormatter: function(point) {
        var intersection = point.sets.join(', '),
          name = point.name,
          ix = point.index + 1,
          val = point.value;
        return ix + '. Intersection: ' + intersection + '. ' +
          (point.sets.length > 1 ? name + '. ' : '') + 'Value ' + val + '.';
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: 'data: {point.name}',
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'venn',
    name: 'ユーザー名',
    data: [{
      sets: ['Good'],
      value: 2,
      name: 'When there are too many characters in the title of this section, it is very difficult to see. Therefore, I would like to limit the number of characters in the part that is always visible. Also, I would like to be able to see all the letters of the title in the popup when the mouse is hovered.',
      overflow: 'allow',
      crop: false
    }, {
      sets: ['Cheap'],
      value: 2
    }, {
      sets: ['Good', 'Cheap'],
      value: 1,
    }]
  }],
  title: {
    text: 'The Unattainable Triangle'
  }
});
```

> https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css#what-can-be-styled
> However, layout and positioning of elements like the title or legend can not be controlled by CSS.

I thought about styling it with CSS, but I was told that the title attribute cannot be controlled with CSS.

Is there any other way?

What I want to do

- Shorten the name when it has too many characters.
- Display full text on hover

Answer (score 0):

For dataLabel setting use `dataLabels.style.textOverflow`, in `dataLabels.format` you can add HTML tags and if you add class you can change behavior in CSS.

```
  plotOptions: {
    venn: {
      dataLabels: {
        useHTML: true,
        format: '<p class="truncate"><b>{point.name}</b></p>',
        style: {
          textOverflow: 'ellipsis'
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.venn.dataLabels

Comment: By upgrading the patch version, you can now use that option. :+1:
From [7.1.1](https://jsfiddle.net/ykhi/gwnp3fcm/49/) to [7.1.3](https://jsfiddle.net/ykhi/gwnp3fcm/50/)

Comment: Yes, it's work with the updated version https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ogfazd2s/